# Random string picker (string names are exactly the same, except the number)

Tags: string, vb.net, random

```
Dim rnd As New Random
Dim quote1, quote2, quote3 As String
Dim int As Integer

int = rnd.Next(1, 3)
quote1 = "never give up"
quote2 = "always believe in yourself"
quote3 = "always follow your dreams"

MessageBox.Show("quote" & int)
```

Hey, can somebody please tell me, how I can assign the int to the word quote, so every time it would pick a different quote?

Answer (score 1):

With only 3 quotes you can do something like

```
    Dim quoteIndex As Integer = Rnd.Next(1, 3)
    Dim quote As String = ""
    Select Case quoteIndex
        Case 1
            quote = quote1
        Case 2
            quote = quote2
        Case 3
            quote = quote3
    End Select
    MessageBox.Show(quote)
```

But in all honesty it's a quite lame solution, more akin to ninja code than to good practices. Instead, you should use an array or a list (which can be created inside this method or come from somewhere else like an overload or a modal variable):

```
    Dim quoteList As New List(Of String)
    quoteList.AddRange({"never give up", "always believe in yourself", "always follow your dreams", "something else"})

    Dim quoteChoosen As Integer = Rnd.Next(0, quoteList.Count)  'this array start at zero
    MessageBox.Show(quoteList(quoteChoosen))  '
```

If your list evolves over time (assuming that it's stored in a variable somewhere), your method won't need to be updated. Your user could add his own motivational quotes to the list without breaking your code, for an example.

Comment: Thanks for noticing and letting me know @Jimi.

Answer (score 0):

As your code it written, you're showing a string value in the MessageBox.   The string is being appended to, so it is dynamic and random, but it's still a string.

To get the affect I think you're looking for, you would need to use your random value as a pointer of some sort to reference a variable value.  Using an array is probably the most straight-forward way to do that with this code.   Instead of having 3 distinct quote strings values, you could create an array of strings...something like

quote = new string[]

where

quote[0] = "never give up"

then you could do something like MessageBox.Show(quote[int])

Comment: @VladimirsPodmoskovnijs If this answer helped you please mark it as accepted (also an upvote can't hurt).